# HttpURLConnection Post Request, responds with Response from javax.rs.ws.Response Object

Tags: java, web-services, http, httpurlconnection, bytearrayinputstream

I am trying to make one web service call a second web service, The first is somewhat of a thin access layer. My bottom webservice looks like this,

```
@POST
@Path("/savechart")
@Produces("image/png")
public Response saveChart(@FormParam("chartId") String chartId, @FormParam("chartType") String chartType,
                          @FormParam("chartSubType") String chartSubType, @FormParam("authJsonMap") String authJsonMap,
                          @FormParam("chartParameters") String parameters, @FormParam("chartLocation") String chartLocation) {

    try {
        // String dataDetails = " Saved Chart ";
        if (chartId != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(chartId)) {

        }

        // SubProcessService subProcess = DaoRegistry.getSubProcessService();
        PhantomHelper p = new PhantomHelper("phantomjs");

        BufferedImage chart = p.saveChart(chartLocation , chartId, chartType, chartSubType, authJsonMap, parameters);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ImageIO.write(chart, "png", bao);

        byte[] imageData = bao.toByteArray();

        if (imageData == null) {
            return Response.status(210).build();
        }

        p.kill();
        // the request is received
        return Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData))
                .build();
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        System.out.println("Save Chart Exception: " + exe.toString());
        System.out.println("Save Chart Exception: " + exe.getStackTrace().toString());
        exe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return Response.status(500).entity("Error Saving Chart : " + exe.getStackTrace() ).build();
    }

}
```

Its a web service that creates a png file and sends back the image in a Response Object that has a ByteArrayInputStream() as its entity. This works if I send a POST request to it directly, but I want to go through a seperate web service. Here is what I am trying to do to read in the response, and then regurgitate.

```
    public Response POST() throws Exception {

    // Create Post Request
    URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent" , USER_AGENT);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language" , ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);

    // User assigned properties to header
    if (requestProperties != null) {
        for (String key : requestProperties.keySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(key , requestProperties.get(key));
        }
    }

    // Construct URL
    String urlParameters = constructUrl(parameters);

    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

    out.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    return Response.status(200).entity(connection.getInputStream()).build();

}
```

But this doesn't work. I can't figure out how to consume the response, convert it back to a response object and send it through.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this process by reading in the response as a byte array and then responding with a similar ByteArrayOutputStream. Code is below

```
public Response POST() throws Exception {

    // Create Post Request


    URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent" , USER_AGENT);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language" , ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);

    // User assigned properties to header
    if (requestProperties != null) {
        for (String key : requestProperties.keySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(key , requestProperties.get(key));
        }
    }

    // Construct URL
    String urlParameters = constructUrl(parameters);


    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream outStream = connection.getOutputStream();

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outStream);

    out.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    out.flush();
    out.close();


    byte[] input = IOUtils.toByteArray(connection.getInputStream());

    return Response.status(200).entity(new ByteArrayInputStream(input)).build();

}
```